# Target variable found in .actionscript file from FLA?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

I am trying to stop the sound channel below from playing when a movieclip is visible in a flash file, but the variable is located in the .as file which loads in the FLA. How can I target that variable? Right now I am getting "undefiend" for the properties channel and song.

fla:

```
if(myMC == visible){
    channel.stop();
}
else(channel = song.play());
```

.as file:

```
public var channel:SoundChannel;

    public function Main(param:MovieClip) {

                function showXML(e:Event):void {
                    websiteXML = new XML(e.target.data);
                    MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay(3);
                    //trace(websiteXML);
                    popupFunction();

                    var urlStr:String = websiteXML.settings.mp3Url.@srcUrl;
                    var isStreaming:Boolean = websiteXML.settings.mp3Url.@streaming;
                    var song:Sound = new Sound();
                    song.load(new URLRequest(urlStr));

                        setTimeout(function():void {
                                channel = song.play(0, 999);
                                channel.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
                        },1000);
                }
            }
```

Comment: How do you use the .as file? is it loaded from somewhere, is it a class? where do you call it from FLA?

Comment: Yes it loads in the fla as a class.

Comment: then, where is the object created from that class? you need that object to access the "channel" property that you created

Comment: There is no object, it's a sound channel that I am trying to access from the flash file using actionscript. The channel is created in the class file as per the code above. Another idea would be to target the "myMC" instead but from within the class file which I am not sure how to do but it's the other way around. Does that make sense?

Comment: But, you're trying to access the property "channel", which is a public property of that class. Now, in order to call channel.stop(); you need to do it for that class, e.g. via created object or as static variable (class variable). Paste the whole code for the class of the .as file please.

Comment: Here it is: http://pastie.org/8427144